# Equivalent to find_each in DataMapper

Tags: ruby, datamapper

Is there a way to do the equivalent of `ActiveRecord#find_each` in **DataMapper** ?

(`find_each` will iterate over the result of a query by fetching things in memory by batch of 1000 rather than loading everything in memory)

Comment: No DM expert, but how does this look: https://github.com/postmodern/dm-chunked_query?

Comment: dm-chunked works perfectly. Thanks for the tip!

BTW, you should have posted your comment as an answer, so the original poster can give you credit. You can still do so.

Answer (score 1):

I checked `dm-chunked_query` as @MichaelKohl suggested, but I couldn't make it work as I'd expect, it gets the whole collection (I'd expect it to use OFFSET+LIMIT). So I wrote my own extension, it's pretty simple, hope it helps:

```
class DataMapper::Collection
  def batch(n)
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      offset = 0
      loop do 
        records = slice(offset, n)
        break if records.empty?
        records.each { |record| y.yield(record) }
        offset += records.size
      end
    end
  end
end

# Example
Model.all(:order => :id.asc).batch(1000).each { |obj| p obj }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't DM much, but it would not be that hard to write your own, assuming DM lets you apply your own 'limit'and 'offset' manually to queries.

Check out the implementation of find_each/find_in_batches in AR, only a couple dozen lines.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb#L19

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb#L48

Comment: I'm sure I can write it, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is already a way to do it.